# reading foreign letters in sapi voice

Tags: vbscript

I got a code from the web that reads a given statement:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Zira, David

Set Zira = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
Set Zira.Voice = Zira.GetVoices.Item(1)

Set David = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
Set David.Voice = David.GetVoices.Item(0)
David.Rate = 0
David.Speak "the statement that is going to be readed"

Zira.Rate = 0
Zira.Speak "the statement that is going to be readed"
```

But what I wanted is to make it speak a foreign letter which doesn't have an English sound, for example the Amharic letter `በ`. If I put it directly in the code it would give unexpected result. I would be happy if anyone had an idea to share. I woudn't mind if there is a program in other language that can do this.